# Let $p,q$ be primes with $p|(q-1)$, $G$ a group generated by elements $a,b$, with $| a| = p$, $| b| = q$, then $| G| = pq$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p,q$ be primes with $p|(q-1)$, $G$ a group generated by elements $a,b$, with $| a| = p$, $| b| = q$. 
Also, let $t$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_q^\times$ of order $p$ and let $G$ have the property $aba^{−1}=b^t$. 
Prove that $G$ has order $pq$ and consists precisely of the elements $\{b^ia^j : 0\leq i < q, 0\leq j < p\} =H $.

I've been working on this problem for quite a while, and I know that as a consequence of Lagrange's Theorem, we know that $pq \leq |G|$, so it remains to show $pq \geq |G|$. I have tried several different approaches, but my idea now is to show that any element of $G$ is in $H$ to show $G\subseteq H$, so the second inequality follows.

Does this suffice to show what I want? I also have no idea why we need the fact that $|t| = p$, how is that useful or necessary? Any remarks are appreciated.

Comment: Every element $x\in G$ has the form $x=a^{n_1}b^{m_1}a^{n_2}b^{m_2}\cdots a^{n_k}b^{m_k}$, where $0\leqslant n_i<p$ and $0\leqslant m_i<t$. Use the ralation $aba^{-1}=b^t$ iff $ab=b^ta$. Let's see a particular element $a^rb^ma^s$. Write it: $a^rb^ma^s=a^{r-1}(ab)b^{m-1}a^s=a^{r-1}b^tab^{m-1}a^s=a^{r-1}b^t(ab)b^{m-2}a^s=a^{r-1}b^{2t}ab^{m-2}a^s=...=a^{r-1}b^{mt}a^{s+1}$. In general we have $a^{r-u}b^{mt^u}a^{s+u}$. Then $a^rb^ma^s=b^{mt^r}a^{s+r}$. Therefore, for an arbitrary element $x=a^{n_1}b^{m_1}a^{n_2}b^{m_2}\cdots a^{n_k}b^{m_k}=b^va^w$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What about why the order of $t$ has to be $p$. I know this has something to do with the fact that these representations must be unique to be well-defined or something like that, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: My English it is rusty anf I don't understand your difficulty. Is my suggestion not enough for your conclusion?